# Syntax for executing a script using Git Bash on Windows 10 pro/docker/ddev

Tags: bash, wget

I am executing the following command:

```
 wget -O -https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh | bash
```

And I get the following:

```
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

Looks as if I have the syntax wrong, but I have been searching to find out how to fix this and haven't found an answer.

I checked the command on shellcheck.net and learned the following:

```
SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
```

That sounds great, but I don't (yet) know what it means.

Comment: `-http://...` → `http://...`

Comment: As for what ShellCheck is saying (it’s unrelated to the `wget` problem; ShellCheck doesn’t check such things): [Read up on shebangs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: Perhaps you misread an example. `wget -O - http://... | bash` (note the space) would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-O`, which means that the next argument is the output file. Hence,

```
-https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh
```

is the name of your output file, and there is no URL in your command.

Since you are piping the result of wget into *bash*, you don't need an output file, I think.

Comment: Just tried this:
'wget -https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh | bash'
which resulted in:
bash: line 1: GNU: command not found
bash: line 2: Usage:: command not found
bash: line 4: Mandatory: command not found
bash: line 6: Startup:: command not found
bash: line 7: -V,: command not found
bash: line 8: -h,: command not found
bash: line 9: -b,: command not found
bash: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: line 210: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Still working on it...

Comment: Yeah, just `wget <url>` will do. Or `curl -O <url>`

Comment: Don't pipe it to bash... Run it manually per the instructions: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/performance/#windows-nfs-setup - it sure is amazing how many things there are to learn in the world, isn't it. It's frustrating.

Comment: Now also removed the - in front of the URL (as per @Biffen above) and it seems to have worked: Input ' wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/windows_ddev_nfs_setup.sh | bash'

Comment: @rfay, you were posting your comments while I was executing the command and writing my last comment. Hopefully I did not do anything that screwed things up too much. In any case, if I did something wrong then I will look for ways to revert. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling just about everything more than once at this point. It's a good thing I find these kinds of puzzles enjoyable--it helps offset the frustration of knowing how much time I am putting into the plaform rather than the website. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @femrich : It's not THAT much a puzzle; I just wonder why you always are happily distributing hyphens in your command. In particular at the start of an URL, they don't make much sense. You wouldn't write them in the URL field of a web browser either, would you?

Comment: @user1934428, I am a newbie working with docs written for developers; they give general instructions on how to do things without specific commands which, at this point, I need. So after reading general instructions I search for examples of commands, copy-paste them, and adjust for the specifics of my requirements. The hyphens were part of an example command I found online. At this point, none of it makes much sense to me, though if past experience serves it will begin to make sense in time. Thanks for calling my attention to the oddity of hyphens--will try to understand that as i move forward.

Comment: You'll go far! It's so, so hard to walk into technologies like this. And you've walked into a whole bunch of them at once. Take your time, learn the underlying things as you get a chance, spend the time to fill in the gaps. @user1934428 remember back the last time you walked into something where you had no context? Go easy! I spent the last couple of days trying to find my way around a CMS and related technology I had little experience with. It's HARD!